# Track and Plan adding iterations in Bluemix DevOps

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, rtc

I am the project owner and I need to add iterations since the project has been extended.  I get a permissions error when editing the timeline via Track and Plan Dashboard -> Plans -> Iterations.

Is there another way to add iterations?   As a project owner, how do I not have permission?

Comment: Hi Joe. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide the exact error message that you are seeing? That information will help people to help you more quickly.

Comment: Absolutely!   Here is what I see

Comment: That error is from the Timelines page when I try and save a new iteration.  Sorry about the formatting - I'm a stackoverflow newbie and didn't notice the formatting info until too late.

Comment: Project area cannot be saved  

Problem  
CRJAZ6053E The 'Save Project Area' operation cannot be completed. Permission is required to complete the operation.
  
Reason  
In order to carry out this operation, you would need permission to perform the following additional actions:  
Modify the structure of iterations  
Modify the collection of timelines

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the TRACK & PLAN UI to manage timelines (To get there click the "Track & Plan" button, "Sprint Planning" from the left nav, "Add Sprint").